# How to distribute java app with SQLite

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, maven, executable-jar

I am trying to create a runnable jar of a java app. I am using Hibernate and Spring. My project is a maven project with the following structure:

```
src
-----/main
----------/java
---------------/com
--------------------/project
-------------------------/main.java
----------/resources
---------------/database.db
pom.xml
```

This is some of my POM file

```
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.31</version>
    </dependency>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I am using hibernate to communicate with an sqlite database to perform **read and write** operations. The .xml configuration for hibernate:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/database.db" />
</beans:bean>
```

I would like to be able to distribute the app with the database for the user to use. I have read that sqlite is an embedded database. However I have also found on google mentions that it is read only when you put it in a .jar. How can I distribute the database with the app in a secure manner? (secure meaning it cannot be overwritten, opened or read easily).

Comment: the moment you ship the database to the consumer it isn't secure anymore. It's trivial to extract database from jar(a jar is just a zip) and then open it in an sqllite manager. Any program with the right permissions could do this easily.

Comment: @Tschallacka I am not requiring full and complete security. I just want to be sure that the database is not easily accessible and cannot be overwritten easily.

Comment: is it a static-read only database? if so, apply a checksum test before interfacing, do a critical exception if modified.

Comment: @Tschallacka I need to be able to perform read and write operations

Answer (score 0):

You are lost as soon as you hand it over (as Tschallacka said).

You have few options here (but they will only "reduce the damage"):

- checksums (to verify consistency of database)
- embed your database creation queries inside code and, in case someone played with it, recreate it
- use in memory solution instead:

https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevdvlpinmemdb.html
https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

But you still have to protect your saved state (e.g. by encrypting it).

Comment: This would still be readable easily taking the sqlite tool, unless you use encryption and inmemorydb but with some limitation (the memory itself).

Comment: Yes, sure. That's why I have stated that after handing anything to end users you are helpless. The only thing you can do is to limit the damage.

Comment: Since you followed that statement with "_You have few options here_", it was not clear